# how do I set the width of the xterm scrollbar

Tags: xterm, scrollbar

I'm running ubuntu 20.04.     I've just obtained a new laptop with very high resolution (3840x2400) and so my xterm windows are tiny by default.   I can increase the font size to compensate for the tinyness, but the scroll bar is still impossibly narrow.    Could somebody tell me how I might widen it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following lines to my .Xresources

```
 xterm*scrollBar: true
 xterm*rightScrollBar: true  
 xterm*Scrollbar*width: 14
```